# MongoDB average on dynamic keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm not sure if this is possible in pure `mongo`. I have looked at [Mongo Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and [Map Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#map-reduce).

I have the following `collection`:

```
{
    id: 1
    activity: "running"
    result: {
        distance: 10
        duration: 20
    }
},
{
    id: 2
    activity: "running"
    result: {
        distance: 30
        duration: 40
    }
},
{
    id: 3
    activity: "weightlifting"
    result: {
        reps: 10
        weight: 30
    }
}
```

Now I would like to get the `average` of any `field` within the `result` part of the `item` in the `collection` of a certain type.

For example: I fetch all the `running` `activities` and want the average of `distance` and `duration`. However I want to query that dynamically. Without explicitly stating `distance` and `duration`. The only thing I know is: "The fields I want are within the `results` part of the object."

The output would be something like:

```
{
    activity: "running"
    result: {
        distance: 20
        duration: 30
    }
}
```

Currently I have a solution that fetches all activities of a certain type into `Node`, and use `Javascript` to determine the average dynamically. Though I'm curious to see if I can do this in `Mongo` directly.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is not exactly average, but mapreduce: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/#calculate-order-and-total-quantity-with-average-quantity-per-item